# React-Native - Make dynamic component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using TabNavigator from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab, I want to return my component dynamically with the state.routeName.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text} from 'react-native';



export default class DashboardSelectionTab extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    const {state} = this.props.navigation;
```

I get the following state.routeName here i.e "Day", "Week", "Month", "Custom" for the each Tab accordingly

```
    const Day = () => (
      <Text>Day</Text>
    );

    const Week = () => (
      <Text>Week</Text>
    );

    const Month = () => (
      <Text>Month</Text>
    );

    const Custom = () => (
      <Text>Custom</Text>
    );
```

I did this but I get syntax error.

```
    return <{state.routeName } />
  }
}
```

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this:

```
return <div>
            {this.renderComponent(state.routeName) } 
        </div>



renderComponent(name){
    switch(name){
        case 'Day': return <Day/>;
        case 'Month': return <Month/>
        default: <Default/>
    }
}
```

Check the working example:

```js
const Day = () => (
    <div>Day</div>
);

const Week = () => (
    <div>Week</div>
);

const Month = () => (
    <div>Month</div>
);

const Custom = () => (
    <div>Custom</div>
);

class DashboardSelectionTab extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {compName: 'Day'}
    }

    renderComponent(){
        switch(this.state.compName){
            case 'Day': return <Day/>;
            case 'Month': return <Month/>;
            case 'Week': return <Week/>;
            case 'Custom': return <Custom/>
        }
    }

    render() {
   return(
             <div>
               {this.renderComponent() } 
               <br/>
               <select 
                value={this.state.compName}
                onChange={(event)=>this.setState({compName: event.target.value})}
               >
                   <option value='Day'>Day</option>
                   <option value='Week'>Week</option>
                   <option value='Month'>Month</option>
                   <option value='Custom'>Custom</option>
               </select>
          </div>
       )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<DashboardSelectionTab/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```